# How can a templated function modify it's behaviour at compilation time depending upon the type?

Tags: c++, templates, pointers, compilation

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

class A
{
public:
   int attr;
   A(int a):attr(a){}
};

template <typename T>
int sum(std::vector<T> x)
{
  int s = 0;
  for (auto& elem : x)
  {
      s += elem.attr; // Problem is here, when elem is a pointer
  }
  return s;
}

int main()
{
   std::vector<A> x1 = {1,2,3,4,5};
   std::cout << "sum = " <<  sum(x1) << "\n";

   std::vector<A*> x2;
   for (auto& elem : x1)
     x2.push_back(&elem);

   std::cout << "sum = " <<  sum(x2) << "\n"; // Problem is this function call

   return 0;
}
```

The above does not compile as `elem.attr` is undefined for `A*`. It should be `elem->attr`.

Is there a way make this work without having to rewrite the entire function `sum`?

Of course, `sum` is a very small function but for bigger functions, it starts to become a bit of a design issue to copy paste a long code. I would have been tempted to use `if (std::is_pointer<elem>::value)` but of course, this does not solve the problem as the evaluation is made at run time and not at compilation time.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Constexpr If](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/if#Constexpr_If) (since C++17), which works at compilation time.

> If the value is true, then statement-false is discarded (if present), otherwise, statement-true is discarded.

e.g.

```
if constexpr (std::is_pointer_v<T>) {
    s += elem->attr; // when elem is a pointer
} else {
    s += elem.attr;  // when elem is not a pointer
}
```